# Unremovable conflict in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I've got a file-conflict in TFS that I cannot get rid of:

[image]

If I click **AutoResolve** it says:

> No conflict has been resolved due to conflicting content changes, name
>   changes or encoding changes. These conflicts will need to be resolved
>   individually

but it doesn't give me any merge-options.

I've tried unmapping and deleting the workspace from disk and re-adding it, but the conflict is still there.
Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Edit, the problem seems to be caused by a name change of a file. The file on disk is missing a letter compared to the file in the error message.

Comment: Have you changed computers or computer names recently? Was the server moved? Any changes to the TFS workspace? Anything like that?

Comment: we are using team foundation service, but I have not changed computer since starting in the project. A lot of changes in the workspace however...

Comment: I have seen changes like these sometimes orphan changes in an abandoned workspace. If you still have access to workspaces you've left behind, you could look to see if something remains checked out there that you can undo. Also, even though you have no pending changes, see if undo is an option anyway.  Sorry if this sounds a little bit like "get a bigger hammer and bang harder", but basically it sounds like you're in a corrupt state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not find the cause so I could not solve the problem in a desired way. Since remapping the workspace did not get rid of the conflict i finally ended up with removing my TFS-workspace and creating it all over. I can only assume that the cause was due to some kind of bug.

Comment: I ended up having to do the same to fix it successfully. In my case it was also due to a file rename, followed by a tf destroy.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this situation using tf from the command line.

```
tf resolve <filename> /auto:keepyours
```

but I think I should have used

```
tf resolve <filename> /auto:deleteconflict
```

In any case, keepyours set my local file as the chosen file and removed the conflict from VS.

documentation at:  [MSDN Resolve Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yw3tcdy.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are unfortunately no merge options to provide in this case.  A conflict of type "Target Local Pending" indicates that the local item is being renamed and the target of the rename *also* has a change that conflicts with the rename.

I recommend you back up any changes to that file and undo the pending change to remove the conflict, then proceed.

Comment: I didn't mention it clearly, but I do not have any pending changes that i can undo...

Comment: @juni-j I'm not sure how you could have a conflict, then?  Do you have changes in your working folders that are not pended?  What is the operation that has created this conflict?  A get?  A merge?  A checkin?

Comment: Honestly I don't know how it occurred but it seems to be a name change of a file that caused this. Basically I have a conflict that I can not resolve and no pending changes.